# ArcGIS pro import modules error

Tags: arcpy, installation, arcgis-pro, pycharm

I am currently using python 3.5 interpreter to run pycharm and ArcGIS Pro version 1.1. But my pycharm is unable to recognize the arcpy package settings and throwing me an error showing underline. Can any-one please clarify how to get ArcPy library

Comment: Did you install python/arcpy from ArcGIS Pro install?  ArcGIS Pro 1.1 comes with Python 3.4 which makes me think you've just downloaded and installed python 3.5 and find arcpy doesn't work.  You need to install the python/arcpy installer that comes with ArcGIS Pro.  Alternatively, upgrade your Pro to 1.3 and it will install python/arcpy for you

Comment: I have Python 2.7 for ArcGIS Desktop 10.3. Will this work for Arc GIS pro 1.1 version. I hope for ArcGIS Pro only from 1.3 version, the python package comes along with the suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcGIS Pro uses Python 3.4 and its own version of arcpy. It is different to Python 2.7 and Desktop 10.3's arcpy. You'll need to install arcpy and python for ArcGIS Pro.

ArcGIS Pro 1.1 has a separate python/arcpy installer, which you will need to use if you want to use arcpy with ArcGIS Pro 1.1. If you don't have access to this installer you will need to update your install to ArcGIS Pro 1.3.1 (current release) which will install arcpy/python 3.4 for you. You can't use a separate install of python.

You can update ArcGIS Pro from within the Pro application by clicking on Project > About.

[image]